# Changing data in List using ListIterator

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

This is a function which I am using to build Megatransactions from given transactions. (Data Mining)

Declaration of `database` is `private List<String[]> database = null;`

Declaration of `MTdatabase` is `private List<String[]> MTdatabase = null;`

Before call of this function `database` has all required data and `MTdatabase` is initially empty.
I am getting data from `database`, modifying it, and then storing it in `MTdatabase`.

I am not modifying any data in `database`, but I don't know why value of `database` is changed.
`MTrans` is modified in the for loop but as I am not using `itrdb.set()`, no data should be modified in `database`.
I don't want to modify `database`.
I tried  to store initial value of `MTrans` in `ntrans` to keep the data of `database` same but `ntrans` is changed each time `MTrans` is changed.
Code for `ntrans` is shown as comment.

```
private void BuildMegaTransactions(List<String> frequent1) {
        MTdatabase = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] MTrans;
        //String[] ntrans;
        int count=0;
        ListIterator<String []> itrdb=database.listIterator();
        while(itrdb.hasNext())
        {
            MTrans=itrdb.next();
            //ntrans=Mtrans;
            int len=MTrans.length;
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                if(Frequent(MTrans[i],frequent1))
                    MTrans[i]=MTrans[i].concat(String.valueOf(count));  

                else
                    {
                    MTrans=removeElements(MTrans,MTrans[i]);
                    len=MTrans.length;
                    i=i-1;
                    }


            }
            //itrdb.set(ntrans);
            MTdatabase.add(MTrans);
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?
What should I do if I don't want to modify `database`?
Is there any way to store the initial value of `MTrans` and use it later?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
MTrans=itrdb.next();
```

assigns `MTrans` as a reference to the next row in `itrdb`.  This means that when you run your lines

```
if(Frequent(MTrans[i],frequent1))
    MTrans[i]=MTrans[i].concat(String.valueOf(count));  
else
{
    MTrans=removeElements(MTrans,MTrans[i]);
    len=MTrans.length;
    i=i-1;
}
```

you are modifying the data in `database`.  To avoid modifying the originals, you should change 
`MTrans=itrdb.next();`
to

```
String [] nextRow = itrdb.next();
MTrans=Arrays.copyOf(nextRow, nextRow.length);
```

Which will create a deep copy of the row in itrdb, which you can then modify without affecting the original.

The key thing to learn here is that while Java is nominally pass by value; for objects the value that is passed is the `reference` to the object in memory.

Comment: Means `itrdb.next()` returns a pointer(as in c) to the object and not the object itself? But in documentation, it showed it would return `String[]` in this case.

Comment: String [] is a reference (pointer) to next result, not a copy of the next result.